# How to make Spinner show items as List inside of Navigation Drawer like in Gmail app?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, navigation-drawer

I want to make a Spinner that functions in the same way as Gmail app.

Specifically, the spinner should replace the menu items of `NavigationDrawer` with the list of items when clicked. I suppose that I should use `ListView` but have no idea where to place it and how to replace menu items with it dynamically.

How can I achieve this functionality? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Thanks to all of the answer! I appreciate your help!

It turns out that using `ImageView` with `TextView` and set `onClickListener` on last instead of `Spinner` was easier way to achieve the desired functionality. On click event I simply hide the menu items and make visible the `ListView` which is nested inside of `NavigationView`. The resulting code looks like this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/header"
                layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/citiesListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingTop="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cityPicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Astana"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pickerArrow"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
// ................

private NavigationView navigationView;
private TextView cityPickerTextView;
private ListView citiesListView;
private ImageView pickerArrow;

private boolean isPickerShown = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ................

    findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    cityPickerTextView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.cityPicker);
    cityPickerTextView.setText(cities[0]);
    cityPickerTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleMenu();
        }
    });
    cityPickerTextView.bringToFront();

    pickerArrow = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pickerArrow);
    pickerArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_white_24dp);

    citiesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.citiesListView);
    citiesListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final CityPickerAdapter adapter = new CityPickerAdapter(this, cities, userCity);
    citiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    citiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            userCity = cities[i];
            cityPickerTextView.setText(userCity);
            adapter.updateCurrentCity(userCity);
        }
    });
}

private void toggleMenu() {
    if (!isPickerShown) {
        pickerArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up_white_24dp);
        setMenuItemsVisible(false);
        citiesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isPickerShown = true;
    } else {
        pickerArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_white_24dp);
        setMenuItemsVisible(true);
        citiesListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        isPickerShown = false;
    }
}

private void setMenuItemsVisible(boolean b) {
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
        menu.getItem(i).setVisible(b);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
    return true;
}

// Rest of the code
```

Comment: Is this how gmail app been done? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Gmail app is not open source and therefore, we can't see the exact code or way Google has implemented it. The method shown here is the solution developed by myself and not sure if anyone does it like this. However, I can say confidently that I found no difference in performance and overall look of the results

Comment: Great Marat! This solution works as expected. But, the navigation menus are placed behind the header. Is there a way to overcome this? I mean, can we set margin to navigation menus?

Comment: Did you include the `findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and `View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);` ?

Comment: @Marat Nice work, thanx, i have tried your code and it worked fine except this `View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    cityPickerTextView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.cityPicker);
    cityPickerTextView.setText(cities[0]);` it just doesn't update the UI, when i call getText it returns the value  i put and also the arrow doesn't show up but from xml it show up in other words any thing related to the nav_header_main doesn't get updated from java, any idea why?

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene did you include this: `findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` before `View headerView...` ?

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene Happy coding :)

Comment: @Marat Can u pelase show the complete code of the above??

Comment: @KJEjava48 The rest of the code has nothing to do with the topic of question. I tried to include everything related to navigation list. What is specifically interesting to you that you couldn't find from answer above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nice library which does all those things for you.

[MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this 
**in you activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Spinner element
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

      // Spinner click listener
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

      // Spinner Drop down elements
      List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
      categories.add("Automobile");
      categories.add("Business Services");
      categories.add("Computers");
      categories.add("Education");
      categories.add("Personal");
      categories.add("Travel");

      // Creating adapter for spinner
      ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
      spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

  // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
```

**in activity.xml**

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
```

for full tutorial refer to this site [android Spinners](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a Spinner. Just use other elements to achieve the same behavior. You can change the list content simply by changing its adapter.

You can see good examples at the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html